# Why console.log shows me nothing?

Tags: javascript

I have a map function, which brings me a lot of strings with different values in some cases (before the map function, I also have a filter function too). 
1st: I'm sure the returns are strings, since I `console.log(typeof thing.name)` and it returns me, well, strings.

In some cases it brings me a lot of strings and in another cases it me brings me nothing, since the return depends on the filter.

The problem is: when the filter brings me no results, the console log do not print anything. I know, it makes sense. But I'm trying to make a conditional which returns me something like "undefined, null, false/true" when filter returns me 0/none/nothing results. It is possible?

I have something like that:

```
filteredOffers.map(offer => {
  if(offer.name === "" || offer.name === null || offer.name === undefined) {
    console.log("Test test test")
  } else {
    return (
      <p>{offer.name}</p>
    )
  }
})
```

Comment: What is `offer` when nothing is logged?

Comment: Your question is clear to me, IMO lacks of relevant code to help you. Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Maybe `filteredOffers` is an empty array and `.map` never runs?

Comment: If filter brings back no results, then why would map run?

Comment: I don't think `.map()` is the right tool for the job anyway, as it always returns an array of the same length as the original array. You're going to get `undefined` "holes" in the array.

Comment: how does your filteredOffers look like? Do you set offer.name as empty || null || undefined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is

> Why console.log shows me nothing?

And in your question you say

> when the filter brings me no results, the console log do not print anything

Where is what is happening.

`.filter` will return a new array with only the elements of the array that have passed some condition and returned `true`. If no conditions are true, it will return an empty array (`[]`).

`.map` will loop throgh an array and return something in this new array, if it's an empty array, `.map` won't run an just return that empty array.

When you say `when the filter brings me no results` it means that `.filter` returned an empty array and when you do `[].map(...)`, the function inside `.map` won't run and it will just return `[]`.

That answers `Why console.log shows me nothing?`, you are doing `[].map(...)` and the function never runs.

Answer (score 1):

testing

```
!offer.name
```

will return true when

- offer.name is undefined
- offer.name is null
- offer.name is false
- offer.name is the empty string ('')
- offer.name is 0

so you might want to filter your offers as follow

```
filteredOffers.filter(offer => !!offer.name)
```

and only then map the output

```
filteredOffers.filter(offer => !!offer.name).map(offer => (<p>{offer.name}</p>))
```